# Get the relative path of the URL with all the parameters in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an URL like below format:

```
http://localhost:8080/search/?N=4294967292&Nr=OR%28db_Analysis_technique%3AGC%29&Ntt=agilent
```

I wanted to get the expected relative URL like below format:

```
search/?N=4294967292&Nr=OR%28db_Analysis_technique%3AGC%29&Ntt=agilent
```

Please find my piece of code to get the relative path but it doesn't return the parameters...

```
var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
var newPathname = "";
for (i = 0; i < pathArray.length; i++) {
  newPathname += "/";
  newPathname += pathArray[i];
}
console.log(newPathname);
```

any help on this.. thanks

Comment: why are you splitting on `/` and then immediately recombining?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/biseradi/1/edit

```
var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
var newPathname = "";
    var newPathname = "";
    for (i = 3; i < pathArray.length; i++) {

      newPathname += pathArray[i] ;
      if (i< pathArray.length-1){
        newPathname += "/";
      }

    }
    console.log(newPathname);
```

Answer (score 1):

To access the query parameters you'll be wanting `window.location.search` - this will include the `?` separator, if needed.

```
var newPathName = window.location.pathname.substr(1) + window.location.search;
```

Comment: Basically correct, but I'd propose to use substr(0) (index 0) to include the preceding slash for a full relative URL.

Comment: @Windwalker the OP didn't want the leading slash.

Answer (score -1):

Try with the below code :-

```
var pathArray[] = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
var newPathname = "";
for (i = 0; i < pathArray.length; i++) {
  newPathname += "/";
  newPathname += pathArray[i];
}
console.log(newPathname);
```

Comment: identical code to the OP's, except it also has a syntax error (`var pathArray[]` isn't legal JS)